# Mysql find_in_set with Join not working in postgres

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

My mysql query is working proper in SQL database server but when i run same query in Postgres database than find set is not working.
below is my query :

```
SELECT omh.id as idd, omh.modified as modified, omh.modified as modified1, 
DATE_FORMAT(omh.modified, '%m/%d/%Y') as only_date, DATE_FORMAT(omh.modified, '%h:%i %p') as only_time

FROM order_memo_history as omh

LEFT JOIN users as usr ON (FIND_IN_SET(usr.user_id, omh.users_id) != 0)

INNER JOIN service_order as so ON omh.order_id = so.o_id
LEFT JOIN users as u ON omh.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE (omh.modified BETWEEN "2017-09-01 06:00:00" AND "2017-10-27 05:59:00")
AND IF((so.merge_company_id='0'),(omh.company_id = 2819), ((omh.order_id = so.o_id AND omh.company_id = so.merge_company_id) OR (so.merge_company_id = 2819 
        AND (omh.group_id = 2819 OR omh.group_id = '0'))))
GROUP BY idd ORDER BY modified ASC
```

I am getting error

```
ERROR:  function find_in_set(integer, text) does not exist
LINE 6: LEFT JOIN users as usr ON (FIND_IN_SET(usr.user_id, omh.user...
```

I have try with string_to_array but not worked

Comment: Show us your code with `string_to_array`.

Comment: find_in_set is mysql in built function not postgres.

Comment: @FahadAnjum :- yes but in postgres database use string_to_array but it not working in my case.

Comment: Why are you using find in set instead you can directly right  usr.user_id = omh.users_id ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391486/rails4-find-in-set-with-pg-not-working , it may helpful to you.

Comment: @FahadAnjum :-  **omh.users_id** this filed have comma separated value so we need to use that function . so you know any function for behave like find_in_set function in postgres sql

Answer (score 0):

**Postgresql Solution**:
Use of functions [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and [`any`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) can help you in getting the desired result.

Following example can give you some understanding on how to apply the function.

In the example below, assume that the string `'2,4,11,5,8,6'` is comma separated user ids from the field `omh.users_id` and values `11`, `1`, `9` are user ids from the field `usr.user_id`.

```
select string_to_array( '2,4,11,5,8,6', ',' ) as sa
     , '11' = any( string_to_array( '2,4,11,5,8,6', ',' ) ) as matched
     , '1' = any( string_to_array( '2,4,11,5,8,6', ',' ) ) as un_matched_1
     , '9' = any( string_to_array( '2,4,11,5,8,6', ',' ) ) as un_matched_2
```

Result would be like this:

```
+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
| sa             | matched | un_matched_1 | un_matched_2 |
| text[]         | boolean | boolean      | boolean      |
+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
| {2,4,11,5,8,6} | t       | f            | f            |
+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: ravinder-reddy :- I need to check two filed in two different table with **!=0**. How to use this in your syntax  **9 = any( string_to_array( '2,4,11,5,8,6', ',' ) ) as un_matched_2**

Comment: Do you know that how can I convert this kind of query in the Node js sequelize method?