# Error When using FIND_IN_SET in Laravel and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

Showing error when using FIND_IN_SET in Laravel and PostgreSQL

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function
> find_in_set(uuid, character varying) does not exist LINE 1

```
$companyData = DB::table('companies')
                ->select('companies.*')
                ->leftjoin("industries",\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(industries.id,companies.indusrty_id)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
                ->where('companies.id',$companyId)
                ->get();
```

Code After suggestion from comments

```
$companyData = DB::table('companies')
                ->select('companies.*')
                 ->join('industries', function($join)
                    {
                         $join->on('companies.indusrty_id', '=', 'industries.id')
                         ->where('industries.id', '=', any (string_to_array('companies.indusrty_id',',')));
                    })
                ->where('companies.id',$companyId)
                ->get();
```

> now showing Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\any()

[image: Table Schema]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails4 FIND\_IN\_SET with PG not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391486/rails4-find-in-set-with-pg-not-working)

Comment: @brombeer any alternative for that . I am working with in Laravel and PostgreSQL

Comment: @SatheeshKumar: the alternative is in the accepted answer of brombeer's link

Comment: @brombeer code updated

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name code updated as per link given.

Comment: `any()` should most likely also be used in a `DB::raw(...)` call